# How to find all methods available in Smalltalk and search by name?

Tags: smalltalk

In Smalltalk, is there a way to search for all methods available (of any object), say, that contain the word `convert` (case insensitive search), and also contain the word `string`? (the method name, not the source code)

Comment: Can you tell us which dialect you are using?

Comment: hm... preferably a more standard way of doing it... otherwise... GNU Smalltalk, Dolphin, Squeak, or Pharo

Comment: By "contain" you mean in the method's source code, or the method's name?

Comment: method's name... added to the question

Answer (score 9):

In Smalltalk you have direct access to all classes, their methods and their source code, so you can go through them.

### Pharo

Go over all the classes and then from each class select all methods that match your needs (or use the Finder tool).

```
Object withAllSubclasses flatCollect: [ :cls |
    cls methods select: [ :method |
        (method selector includesSubstring: 'convert' caseSensitive: false) and: [
        (method selector includesSubstring: 'string' caseSensitive: false) ]
    ]
].
```

### GNU Smalltalk

GST doesn't have as nice API, but it can be done also.

```
(Object withAllSubclasses collect: [ :cls |
    cls methodDictionary ifNotNil: [ :dict |
        dict values select: [ :method |
            (method selector asLowercase indexOfSubCollection: 'convert' asLowercase) > 0 and: [
            (method selector asLowercase indexOfSubCollection: 'string' asLowercase) > 0 ]
        ]
    ]
]) join
```

### VisualWorks

*(also Pharo and Squeak, and with `ifNotNil:` also GNU Smalltalk)*

VW doesn't have `#flatten`, so it's implemented explicitly. For case-insensitive search `#findSameAs:startingAt:wildcard:` can also be used.

```
(Object withAllSubclasses collect: [ :cls |
    cls methodDictionary values select: [ :method |
        (method selector asLowercase findString: 'convert' asLowercase startingAt: 1) > 0 and: [
        (method selector asLowercase findString: 'string' asLowercase startingAt: 1) > 0 ]
    ]
]) inject: #() into: [ :arr :each | arr, each ]
```

### Dolphin

Dolphin seems to have different object model, see [Leandro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34398788/2007760) below.

Comment: can it be done by something like `Object withAllSubclasses map [allMethods] inject [concatArray] contain 'keyword' contain 'keyword2'` (this is just pseudocode)

Comment: `#collect:` is the smalltalk equivalent of `map`, however I am not sure what you mean by `[concatArray]`. What are you adding there?

Comment: get all arrays, add them up to form one big array... (is it inject or can you just use some kind of join)

Comment: I've added alternative code to the answer, is this what you had in mind? Always having it as a single collection and then applying filters on it?

Comment: so i see... kind of wanted to do it in one line.  what i meant by inject is like in Ruby `[[1,3,5], [2,4,6], ["hello", "world"]].inject(:concat)
=> [1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, "hello", "world"]` Interesting... I think I can understand `inject` better than before: it is like to inject an operator in between the elements: `[1,3,5].inject(:+)
=> 9` and `[1,3,5].inject(:-)
=> -7`

Comment: Smalltalk has `inject:into:`, that is equivalent to ruby's `inject(initial) { |memo, obj| block }`. So you could use that to concat collections... e.g. `#(#(1 3 5) #(2 4 6) #('hello' 'world')) inject: OrderedCollection new into: [ :injected :next | injected addAll: next; yourself ].` (it's bit more heavy handed, but normally you would flatten it with `#(#(1 3 5) #(2 4 6) #('hello' 'world')) flattened`)

Comment: Peter, I think that your code is not looking at class methods.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia why wouldn't it? Class is an Object.

Comment: The enumeration you get from `#withAllSubclasses` will visit only classes, not metaclasses. Therefore the methodDictionaries your code will select from will correspond to methods in the instance side of each class.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia How so? It will include all subclasses of `Object`, which means also metaclasses (because in Smalltalk everything is Object). Try `String class isKindOf: Object` or `Object withAllSubclasses includes: String class`.

Comment: This is interesting. In Pharo `#withAllSubclasses` also includes the metaclasses (I didn't know that.) It looks like this is a dialect-dependent behavior. In some dialects (e.g., Dolphin) only classes (and not metaclasses) are collected by `#withAllSubclasses`.

Comment: I've tested it in Pharo and GNU Smalltalk. If Dolphin behaves differently I question their decision for reasons explained above (everything should be an Object).

Comment: if anybody can provide one that works on VisualWorks... I think for example, the `:cls` does not work there

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I've added VW example (which also works in other dialects). Note that `[ :cls | ... ]` is a regular `BlockClosure` syntax supported by all mentioned dialects, including VW.

Answer (score 2):

This may not work on all smalltalk dialects, but it works at least
with squeak and pharo (other smalltalks may have similar tools/classes)

```
SystemNavigation default browseAllSelect:[:e |
(e selector includesSubstring:'convert' caseSensitive:false)
    and:[e selector includesSubstring:'string' caseSensitive:false]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is more a complement to the answer given by @Peter.

Be aware that in some dialects (e.g., Dolphin) the message `#withAllSubclasses` will only collect classes, and not metaclasses. Because of that the enumerations in @Peter's answer should add all metaclasses in an explicit way.

For instance,

```
selectors := OrderedCollection new.
Object withAllSubclasses do: [:class | | matching |
  matching := class selectors select: [:s |
    (s includesString: 'onvert') and: [s includesString: 'tring']].
  selectors addAll: matching.
  matching := class class selectors select: [:s |
    (s includesString: 'onvert') and: [s includesString: 'tring']].
  selectors addAll: matching].
^selectors
```

Note BTW that I've removed the first letter from both `'convert'` and `'string'` to cheaply prevent case mismatches.

Another difference with my code is that it iterates over the `selectors` of a class rather than over its methods.

**UPDATE**

Note that I've used two enumerations because we cannot do this:

```
class selectors , class class selectors select: [:s |
```

etc. The reason is that the `selectors` of a `class` come in a `Set` and these do not understand `#,`.

We could have done instead:

```
all := class selectors addAll: class class selectors; yourself.
all selectors select: [:s |
```

etc. (note the use of `#yourself`)

Comment: Wouldn't `Object withAllSubclasses, Class withAllSubclasses` work also? (So then the matching would be done on a single collection)

Comment: @Peter I'm afraid no. The class `Class` has no subclasses. It has no instances either! The only reason for `Class` to exist is as a mean to put behavior common to all classes (but not to metaclasses)

Answer (score 0):

This is to add different flavor to the list above.

### @Smalltalk/X

```
Object withAllSubclasses flatCollect: [ :cls |
    cls methodDictionary values select: [ :method |
        (method selector includesSubstring: 'convert' caseSensitive: false) and: [
        (method selector includesSubstring: 'string' caseSensitive: false) ]
    ]
].
```